# remote access SQL data source in c#

Tags: c#, sql, datasource

How can I remotely access SQL in c# window application and use Insert , Update and all SQL statements. My Window application is going to be on different server and different network.

I tried below connection string but gets an error

> error "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.)"

```
Data Source= testServer\SqlInstance,50226;Initial Catalog=dbname;UserID=testid;Password=testpassword
```

Please let me if you need more information. 
thanks

Comment: Can the computer running the application "see" `testServer`?  Can you connect to that database from something like SQL Management Studio from that machine?  Is there a firewall between the two?  Any number of things could be blocking access, nearly all of which are unrelated to the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

please make sure to enable TCP/IP at the sql server instance as described here: [Enable the TCP/IP Protocol for a Database Instance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb909712%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) and also make sure that the server is listening at your Port **50226**, since the default MS SQL port for TCP/IP is **1433**. If this still does not work, check if there is any firewall blocking your connection to the SQL server.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to ping the server from your machine. "Different Network" suggests that you may not be able to see it. Are these different subnets within the same company network or are you trying to connect from somewhere completely detached?

If you can ping it, it may be worth checking out the tracert to see where it's going via, is it going via a firewall?

You may need to use an IP address if you're on a different network and your DNS can't resolve the server's name. If you can ping it, then you need to look at possibly getting firewall rules opened, but for a SQL Server, that would potentially be dangerous. Direct access across differnet networks MAY require you to set up a VPN connection on your machine so you can effectively connect from within the same network.

See also [The Sql Server Guide for Setting up Remote Access](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/configuring-ms-sql-server-for-remote-access/)